# How to put one WKInterfaceLabel below WKInterfaceLabel?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

hello all i have new in watchkit development and i have special requirement in which i arrange one WKInterfaceLabel below another WKInterfaceLabel, i try with lots off option like edit postions but WKInterfaceLabel is not set properly can you please help me in this.

1)Position of the first WKInterfaceLabel

[image: first WKInterfaceLabel on top left side position]

2) Position of the second WKInterfaceLabel

[image: second WKInterfaceLabel below first WKInterfaceLabel]

3) Actual Design

[image: Actual Design]

4)Display in Interface file

[image: How WKInterfaceLabels display in storyboard()]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know clearly about your question, but if you want to arrange the label as you want, you should use the Group and change the position, size of width, and height of label.
In your displayInterface File, may be you have one Label out side of your interface. you can change the vertical or horizontal arrange element of group if you want at attribute Window at the right side of Xcode

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are adding both WKInterfaceLabel vertically in WKInterfaceGroup. Set vertical position of both labels as Top.