# WatchKit interface: set button in same horizontal line

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

I am designing a WatchKit application and I want to put two buttons in the same horizontal line. My button size is small and I have tried all ways to set it in the screen. After setting the first button on the right side, I tried to set another in same horizontal line in left side, but I can not move second button in same horizontal line. I am only able to set one button in a horizontal line in a WatchKit storyboard. How can I place the buttons side-by-side?

Comment: done by adding group .we can add one more button ,image,label in adding group to the same horizontal position...

Answer (score 4):

you have do it by setting the button in group and make the group **"Layout"** to **horizontal** in file inspector and your problem is slove

For more understanding follow below link [How to put one WKInterfaceLabel below WKInterfaceLabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29485735/how-to-put-one-wkinterfacelabel-below-wkinterfacelabel)

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a group in the InterfaceBuilder, and then set the layout to horizontal for that added group.
Now you can add multiple items in that group, and they'll all be added horizontally. Default layout for a new group is Vertical.

You can also try adding groups into groups if you want complex hierarchy of views.
Hope this helps.